# Get the  LinearLayout inside a ListView from an Async Task onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 

Tags: android, android-listview

I hope the title is not mis-leading. I am trying to implement `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` of an `AsyncTask` of loading images and am getting this error `"Java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to retain Activity"`. Here is my code for `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`:

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(){
  //final ListView listview = list;

  final int count = list.getChildCount();
    final LoadedImage[] mylist = new LoadedImage[count];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        final ImageView v = (ImageView)list.getChildAt(i); // getting error here
        mylist[i] = new LoadedImage(((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
    }
    return mylist;
}
```

Here is the `Logcat`:

```
05-18 08:43:15.385: E/AndroidRuntime(28130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retain activity {com.MyApps.ImageGen/com.MyApps.ImageGen.Wallpapers}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
05-18 08:43:15.385: E/AndroidRuntime(28130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
05-18 08:43:15.385: E/AndroidRuntime(28130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3100)
05-18 08:43:15.385: E/AndroidRuntime(28130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3216)
05-18 08:43:15.385: E/AndroidRuntime(28130):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:132)
```

Here is my layout with the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I setup the `ListView`:

```
private void setupViews() { 
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setDivider(null);
        list.setDividerHeight(0);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        list.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

my async task and Item Adapter:

```
class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<Object, LoadedImage, Object> {


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bitmap newbitmap = null;
        Uri uri = null;

        String [] img = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){    

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null, null, null);

        } else {
        // cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null, null, null);

         inInternalStorage = true;
        }

        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int size = cursor.getCount();

        if(size == 0){
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no Images on the sdcard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //System.out.println("size equals zero");

            Wallpaper.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no Images on the sdcard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return params;
        }else {

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int ImageId = cursor.getInt(column_index);

            if(inInternalStorage == true){
             uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + ImageId);
         }else {
             uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + ImageId);
         }


         try {
             BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

             BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);

             int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
             int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
             String imageType = options.outMimeType;

             Log.i(TAG, "imageheight = " + imageHeight);
             Log.i(TAG, "imagewidth = " + imageWidth);
             Log.i(TAG, "imageType = " + imageType);

             //options.inSampleSize=4;

             options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, imageWidth, imageHeight);

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
             //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);

             if(bitmap != null){
                 newbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 180, 180, true);
                 bitmap.recycle();
             }
             if(newbitmap != null){
                 publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newbitmap));

             }
         }catch(IOException e){

         }
         //cursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... value){
        addImage(value);
    }

       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
}

private static class LoadedImage {
    Bitmap mBitmap;

    LoadedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }
}

/*Image Adapter to populate grid view of images*/

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<LoadedImage> photos = new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();


    public ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void addPhotos(LoadedImage photo){
        photos.add(photo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView image;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list,null);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.media_image_id);

            //holder.item_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.media_image_id);

            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }   
        //holder.image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

         //String item_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

            holder.image.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position).getBitmap());    

            //holder.item_name.setText(item_name);

        return convertView;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
   ImageView image;
   TextView item_name;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    int image_column_index = 0;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

  if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){


    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj,null, null,null);
  }else{
      cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj,null, null,null);

  }
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);


    String info = cursor.getString(image_column_index);
    Intent imageviewer  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
           imageviewer.putExtra("pic_name", info);
           startActivity(imageviewer);

     cursor.close();
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 2;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    if (width > height) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    } else {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }
}

/*final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 180;

int scale = 1;
if(reqWidth > REQUIRED_SIZE || reqHeight > REQUIRED_SIZE){
    scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int)Math.round(Math.log(REQUIRED_SIZE/(double)Math.max(reqHeight, reqWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
}*/

return inSampleSize;

}
```

other Methods within Async Task:

```
private void loadImages() {
 final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
 if(data == null){
     new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
 }else {
     final LoadedImage[] photos = (LoadedImage[])data;
     if(photos.length == 0){

        new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
     }
     for(LoadedImage photo:photos){
         addImage(photo);
    }
 }

}

private void addImage(LoadedImage... value) {

    for(LoadedImage photo: value){
        imageAdapter.addPhotos(photo);  
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

I am assuming I should first get the root element before I get the `ListView` from the `logcat` error, but I don't know how, I can't seem to find a suitable method from the documentation.

P.S:  I am using an `Activity` and not a `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception tells you that you try to do an invalid cast. My guess is that your row layout isn't a simple `ImageView` like you assume with the cast in the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, instead your row layout probably has a parent `Linearlayout` that wraps the `ImageView`(and other views?!). When you call the method `getChildAt` you get that parent `Linearlayout` which you try to cast to a `ImageView`. Instead you should do this:

```
//...
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)list.getChildAt(i);
        final ImageView v = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_imageview_from_theRow_layout);
        mylist[i] = new LoadedImage(((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
}
```

Note: The `getChildAt` method returns the rows views for the visible rows only so if you try to access the `View` for a row that isn't currently visible you'll most likely end up with a `NullPointerException`(you should get the drawables directly from the adapter and not from parsing all the rows `Views`).

**Edit based on the comments**:

If I understood your problem, the behavior you see it's normal. You didn't say how you ended up getting the bitmaps in the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` but my guess is that you just save the images from the `ListView` rows that are currently visible to the user. When it's time to restore the adapter with the images from `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` you end up getting only those images which were previously visible. This will get worse if you rotate the phone again as, most likely, there are fewer images visible in landscape orientation then in the portrait orientation.

I don't know if this will work but you could try to modify the `LoadedImage` class to store the `id` of the image from `MediaStore.Images.Media`. When it's time to save the configuration, stop the `LoadImagesFromSDCard` task and  *nullify* all the images(remove the `Bitmap` to which `LoadedImage` points)from the `LoadedImages` `ArrayList`(in the adapter) except the ones that are currently visible to the user. Send the *photos* `ArrayList` from your adapter through 
`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`.

When it's time to restore the adapter set the *photos* `ArrayList` of your new adapter to the one you got back and put the `ListView` to the position of the visible images(so the user sees the sent images). In the `getView` method of your adapter  you'll put a default image(like *loading...*) when you have a `null` value for the `Bitmap` in the associated `LoadedImage` class. Start a new `LoadImagesFromSDCard` task to get the images and parse them again. When you get the `id` from `MediaStore.Images.Media` you'll check if a `LoadedImage` with this `id` exists in the adapter and if it has a `Bitmap` set to it. If it doesn't exist(or it doesn't have a `Bitmap` associated) then load the image and put it in the adapter, if not the image already exists and move to the next one.

I don't know if the solution above will work or if it's efficient. I would recommend you to modify the code and load images on demand instead of loading all up in a big task.

Comment: thanks, it works but the only trouble now is that, the last images visible on screen when the screen orientation changes is only being shown in the new orientation layout; but you can see that the images are still being loaded in the background. espercially when one clicks on the image, it shows the correct image in the list but the screen only still shows the last ones visible during orientation. Hope i made some sense in that. any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @sparrow I didn't understand, edit your question an try to explain better(and also post the code for the `AsyncTask` and the custom adapter(if any) where you set the images). When there is a orientation change the activity will be recreated but the `AsyncTask` will continue to do it's background task(so it's normal to see it in the background doing stuff). You probably see only the last visible images because these are the only ones you send to the new activity.

Comment: what i meant is this.. if am scrolling through my list in vertical orientation, when i switch to horizontal orientation, the last visible images (lets say 4 images), are now shown in the horizontal orientation and the scroll is just large enough for those visible 4 images. now if i scroll so that i can only see 2 images on the screen in horizontal orientation, when i switch back to vertical orientation, only those 2 images are now on the screen. Its like it keeps cutting them. I have posted my async task and adapter code.

Comment: if you can please take a look at my async task and adapter code when you have time, i will really appreciate it. Thank you